# unkowen classes after decompile using jdax/dex2jar

Tags: java, android, dax, decompiling, smali

I get random classes and object within real classes after decompile using jdax or dex2jar
for example in this class I found inside more than 4 unknown object pb4,w64,mb4,f84,h84

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Random;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class AppController extends Application {
    public static pb4 h;
    public static AppController i;
    public boolean b = false;
    public boolean c;
    public Activity d;
    public int e = 0;
    public w64 f;
    public int g;

    static {
        Class<AppController> cls = AppController.class;
    }

    public static pb4 a() {
        if (h == null) {
            try {
                h = mb4.a(f84.a);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return h;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController b() {
        AppController appController;
        synchronized (AppController.class) {
            appController = i;
        }
        return appController;
    }

    public void a(Context context) {
        h84.a().c(context);
        h84.a().a(context);
        h84.a().b(context);
    }

    public void a(pb4 pb4) {
        try {
            b().e = 1;
            String string = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "android_id");
            JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
            jSONObject.put("DeviceId", string);
            jSONObject.put("app_name", getString(R.string.app_name));
            jSONObject.put("package", "com.sandeepappd.videocallworldandvideo");
            jSONObject.put("version", "3");
            jSONObject.put("d_type", "Android");
            JSONObject jSONObject2 = new JSONObject();
            jSONObject2.put("en", "Mini_App_register");
            jSONObject2.put("data", jSONObject);
            pb4.a("req", jSONObject2);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        i = this;
        new Random().nextInt(3001);
        this.f = new w64(this);
    }

    public void onTerminate() {
        h84.a().a(getApplicationContext());
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

I get random classes and object within real classes after decompile using jdax or dex2jar
for example in this class I found inside more than 4 unknown object pb4,w64,mb4,f84,h84 
and something happen with many other classes

another example https://ibb.co/QmxV0X0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of Obfuscate progress when app is build. The idea of Obfuscate is Making the code become hard to read, understanding after decompiling. For more information, you should search the keywords `Obfuscate`

Comment: so the developer use those keywords "pb4,w64,mb4,f84,h84 " Intentionally to Obfuscate me

Comment: Those variables is generated automatically by the tool. Example, we have `proguard` for Android.

Comment: as far as I know, Have no solution for this know. Actually, you still can understand the logic, but it takes time

Comment: Hi @YassinBellal, could you please mark my answer the answer, as it is fit with your question. The question regarding how to decompiled code with more readable should be another question. Thanks